# code igniter can't remove index.php from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have my codeigniter library under a folder called 'codeigniter' (very original) so I visit it at this address which loads fine, http://mysite.co.uk/codeigniter/index.php/pages/view/about

However I can't get to my 'about' page using the following address http://mysite.co.uk/codeigniter/pages/view/about URL without the 'index.php' in the address, it keeps hitting my default controller instead of my pages controller.

I've updated the following:

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysite';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /codeigniter/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Make `$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysite';` to be `$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysite/';` - notice ending slash. It is proposed by [docs](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L10). Secondly, try with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]` - notice question mark (some servers require that fix). And last but not least, redirection could be matter of `APPPATH . 'routes.php'`, maybe?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried the first 2 suggestions but still no luck. What do you mean by the APPPATH? What change should be made?

Comment: `APPPATH` is `CI` constant for your `/codeignter/application/` directory, so I made mistake, I meant `APPPATH . 'config/routes.php'` file. Just was asking myself if something there could result that way you have described.

Comment: I have to .htaccess files, one on the same level as the 'system' directory and another inside the 'application' directory. Which one do I need to update?

Comment: None of those. Those files serve to deny approach to respective directories. Generally, you should change only one that is next to (as same level as) `index.php` file.

Comment: The .htaccess file next to my index.php is on the same level as the 'system', 'application' directory , so this would be the right one wouldn't it?

Comment: Correct. That is only one (in general rule - one in publicly reachable location) supposed to be changed.

Comment: On reWriteBase do I need /codeigniter. If I don't I get an error 'The document name you requested (/index.php/pages/view/about) could not be found on this server.' It still doesn't work with the /codeigniter though. It loads my homepage controller/view.

Comment: That should also end with slash as shown in question code. To answer more, I should see your controller and routes files.

Comment: Here is my code http://pastebin.com/JT5gAQ2X. It's just basic, I just want to get it up and running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106463/discussion-between-tpojka-and-jonathan-lockley).

Comment: Your custom created routes should be placed after default ones come with framework fresh installation. So put `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';` at the end of file. (Read on [URI Routing](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) what you need to carry about when using wildcard route). Remove slash from here `if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))` (check the difference).

Comment: Thanks. Made those changes but no luck. What would be a very basic route/controller to load say http://mysite.co.uk/about with the re-write in place to remove index.php?

Comment: Can't say what is wrong there. It would be redundant, but you can do that with about/index (controller/method). Since it is basicly start of application, reinstall it and start again. Try with [this](http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/) `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the "AllowOverride All" was in placed in your Apache configuration file for the .htaccess to be worked.

Comment: Where would I find my Apache config file? I'm pretty new to PHP I'm a Python dev usually

Comment: It is located on Apache installation directory under the conf directory. You should be able to see the httpd.conf. That is the main configuration file of Apache. Look for AllowOverride then restart the Apache service.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use This in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
        #RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
        #RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F]
</IfModule>  
#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript
</ifmodule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header add Cache-Control:  "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
#End Gzip
# BEGIN Expire headers  
<ifModule mod_expires.c>  
    ExpiresActive On  
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"  
</ifModule>
```